# pear mail, setting and using

Tags: php, email, pear

I am a begginer, so please advise. 
Facts : try to use pear's mail and make it work. I installed pear, mail, and Net. I use Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, Windows 7. The whole system is installed localy on my laptop. Does this makes any difference? Also, I have no clue if my apache supports smtp. I used [this](http://goonanism.com/blog/2010/06/08/using-pear-to-send-email-via-smtp/) as guideline.

This is my code (try to create a simple "forgot my password", not finished)

```
     <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
//connect to db
     include_once('connection.php');
     include('Mail.php');
    //came from login form
    $logf = $_POST['logf'];  

//query according to logf    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT mail FROM table where usrnm = :nm");
    $stmt->bindParam(':nm', $nm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $nm=$logf;

    $data=array('nm'=>$nm);
    $result=$stmt->execute($data);

      $d=0;
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $be[$d]=$row['mail'];
      $d++;}


         $mes="ελα";
            //mail came from query
         $email = $be[0];
         $message = $mes;

         $from = 'Website Enquiry ';
         $to = "Hammy Goonan ";
         $subject = "ανακτηση";
         $body = $message;
         $host = "localhost";
         $headers = array ('From' => $from,
             'To' => $to,
             'Subject' => $subject
         );
         $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
             array ('host' => $host,
                 'auth' => false,
                 'port' => '25'
             )
         );
         $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
         if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {echo($mail->getMessage());}
         else {echo("Message successfully sent!");}

    ?>
```

I get this error :

> Failed to connect to localhost:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: ��� ���� ������ � ���������� ��������, ������ � ����������� ���������� ��� �������� ������. (code: -1, response: )]

Plese help, I've read tutorials and I dont know how to fix this. Actually, I dont know where to begin.

Thanks.

EDIT
I also tried [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/tr/package.mail.mail.send.php) (example section) that uses sendmail, but i dont understand the following

```
$params['sendmail_path'] = '/usr/lib/sendmail';
```

Sendmail also needs smtp erver?

Comment: Do you have a mailserver running on the laptop?

Comment: You still need an SMTP server running locally, since you specified "localhost".

Comment: @ceejayoz No, none. Just apache, php, postgreSQL. Oh, and geoserver

Comment: Well, what at `localhost` where you expecting would handle the e-mail, then?

Comment: @ Marc B @ceejayoz I just edited my question...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `localhost` as the address for your mail server, `localhost` has to *have* a mail server installed.

You need to either install a mail server (there are some development-oriented ones like [Devnull](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp)) or (generally easier) just point it at your ISP's SMTP server for sending purposes.

Comment: @ ceejayoz what (free) mail server you suggest?

Comment: @slevin I linked to one in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `localhost` as the address, you will need to make sure that `localhost` (Your Laptop) has a mailserver installed.

Alternatively, you could use an email sending service like SendGrid and use their SMTP server or as another answer suggest's, point it to your ISP's SMTP server.

Comment: It says your using Window's in your question - sendmail will not be configured like that for windows. `/usr/lib/sendmail` is aimed at Linux users.

Comment: @ ajtrichards what (free) mail server you suggest?

Comment: Send grid offersa free package. Alternatively, you could google "free windows smtp server" and choose one you find appropriate :)